# 'High' as an adjective for 'size'

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

The *size* and *number* of red stains on the metallic tray became *higher*

I wonder if 'higher' could be used for both 'size' and 'number'.

Second of all, shouldn't it be modified to "The *size* and *number* of red stains on the metallic tray became *bigger* and *higher*, respectively."

Comment: Numbers can *rise*, so I suppose they could get *higher*, but it doesn't work for *size* in that sentence. Try using *increased* instead of *became higher* or the double-barrelled '*and*'s.

Comment: The sentence might be grammatically correct but "the red stains on the metallic tray became larger, and the number of stains increased' seems more natural

Comment: Are you wedded to this construction? Why not just say *Both the size and number of red stains on the metallic tray increased*?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it's correct, in regular speech (American Southeast), I tend to use a modifier that fits the *last* item in a set, if the modifier for the other item expresses a similar idea. Your sentence is a perfect example of how I would use this speech pattern.

That being said, if I were writing, I would tend to notice that the modifier doesn't match correctly and edit the sentence exactly the way Lawrence suggested: That is, I would change *rise* to *increase*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I believe you could use "greater".

> The size and number of red stains on the metallic tray became bigger
>   and higher, respectively.

I'd suggest that this is as bad as the alternatives you've given. It achieves technical accuracy at the price of becoming annoyingly pedantic.